# I'm unable to find by _id on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find() by _id using Node.js and MongoDB.

I'm able to show objects in the database when using an alternative parameter, or using no parameters at all. Here's my code and results to show that:

```
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;
    db.collection('listings').find().toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

The results I get back are this:

> [{"_id":"5a1ff1ac32fe0a2bd966be1e","title":"hi","price":"5"},{"_id":"5a207cea2f119cbd6a5fa688","title":"hello","price":"10"}]

When I modify the code to find the results using the title "hi" I get back this:

> [{"_id":"5a1ff1ac32fe0a2bd966be1e","title":"hi","price":"5"}]

using the following code:

```
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;
    db.collection('listings').find({'title': 'hi'}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

**However** when I try to sort by _id using this code:

```
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;
    db.collection('listings').find({'_id': '5a1ff1ac32fe0a2bd966be1e'}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

The results I get back is

> []

**The question is: how do I find by _id so that when I use _id I can get back results for that specific _id?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'5a1ff1ac32fe0a2bd966be1e'` is a string.

`_id` is of type `ObjectId`.

You can make an object id with `ObjectID('5a1ff1ac32fe0a2bd966be1e')`. You can require the function like this:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is the documentation.